# Razl connection error "Can't install connector. The web root can't be found"

Tags: razl

When trying to create a connection to a Sitecore environment with the Hhogdev Razl sync tool, I get the error

> The connector test failed. The reason is 'Can't install connector. The web root can't be found'

[image]

The site is running under HTTPS and I am using the "Package Connections" option in the Razl connection wizard.

Comment: Not sure if your issue has been solved already but I have the same setup (also on azure web apps) and I got this error when the template for a certain item wasn't available on the destination machine.

Comment: Hi Matthew if my site is running in an Azure WebApp how can I get the access guid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My site is running in an Azure WebApp and it seems that you need to use the hostname that ends with `.azurewebsites.net`.

Comment: You think Razi is looking for that name to alter its functionality? Or it just needed a more qualified name?

Comment: @dnstommy I doubt that. Maybe it could be something to do with how DNS are redirected to the azurewebsites domain which breaks the Razl connection. I would be interested to hear if other people experience the same issue?